# Sync .bib file in overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf

I've compiled the citation of a few articles in .bib file. The citation keys in .bib file (uploaded from a local folder) are used for adding references in the tex file in Overleaf. The .bib file has been created using Mendeley.

When I add new references to Mendeley, the .bib file in the local folder is updated.
However, the .bib in overleaf has to be overwritten each time when new citation keys have to be updated.

I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically sync the .bib file in the local folder to overleaf.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ You can put the .bib file in Google Drive, Dropbox  or any other cloud-storage services that would generate a URL to access the file. You can then add the .bib as a linked file to your Overleaf project using this URL. See https://www.overleaf.com/help/247 under the heading "Linked File". You may also want to contact support@overleaf.com if you have further questions about this!

Comment: @LianTzeLim Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to know if it is possible to link from Git repository in unpaid version of Overleaf

Comment: It would be best to email support@overleaf.com for Overleaf-specific features, but to answer your query: you can use the "Raw" url of a file in a Github repository to Import one specific file to your project. But you'll need an Overleaf subscription indeed if you want to use the Git bridge or direct Github sync, for working with entire projects/repos.